# Find open generic classes that would be assignable to a certain closed generic interface when closed with same parameters

Tags: c#, generics, types

Assume we have an interface `IService<T>` and an implementation `Service<T> : IService<T>`. Further we have an implementation `SpecialService : IService<int>`

How can I find all types in the assembly that are assignable to `IService<int>`, so that I get `SpecialService` as well as the closed type `Service<int>`?

Update: `EdgeCaseService<T, U> : IService<T>` should not be considered, since this would result in (nearly) infinite possibilities. Only classes with same count auf generic arguments are considered, in this case one.

Comment: There could be an infinite number of closed types. Consider `class Foo<T, U>: IService<T>` for example. `Foo<int, string>` is assignable to `IService<int>`, and so is `Foo<int, object>`, `Foo<int, int>` and so on. What do you want to do in cases like this?

Comment: Good point. We can assume to only consider classes with one generic argument.

Comment: Okay, is the interface you are checking against (`IService<int>`) known at compile time or do you need an algorithm that works with any type given as a `Type` instance at runtime? The latter is a *lot* harder as you can imagine.

Comment: I am already within another class that provides `T` so I can work with `IService<T>` directly, which should be closed at runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to Ibram's answer, you can also see if the type directly implements the filled generic type, or is itself a generic type that allows the internal type argument:

```cs
    var implemetations = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(x =>
        {
            if (x.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IService<int>)))
                return true;

            if (!x.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
                return false;

            try
            {
                return x.MakeGenericType(typeof(int))
                    .IsAssignableTo(typeof(IService<int>));
            }
            catch(ArgumentException)
            {
                // Unable to assign int to generic paramter on type
                return false;
            }
        });

public interface IService<T>
{
    
}

public class IntService : IService<int> { }

public class Service<T> : IService<T> { }

public class ClassService<T> : IService<T> where T: class { }
```

This would return Service where `Service<T>` and `IntService` but not `ClassService`

Comment: Nice to see it considers constraints implicitely. I was missing the idea of MakeGenericType

Comment: But that would return the unbound generic class, correct?

Comment: @Creepin, it would indeed.  In a purely generic solution, I'd want to split unfilled `IService<>` from the type parameter `int` and then exclude the unfilled type from the results

Comment: You could filter on `.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1`. I would also consider introducing a non-generic interface `interface IService{} interface IService<T>:IService{}`, which you could use as a filter. But just throwing the exception is probably fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [Reflection](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-reflection-in-c-sharp/)

```
using System.Reflection;

var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var specialTypes = asm.GetTypes().Where(u => u.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IService<int>)));
 
foreach (var itemType in specialTypes)
{
    // Display each type 
    Console.WriteLine("Class : {0}", itemType.FullName); 
     
}
```

Comment: I think that would find `SpecialService` but not `Service<T>` closed with `int`, correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right ... this is only giving you open types that are assignable to `IService<int>` ... Patrick's answer, I guess it meet your requirement